# function that reads JSON to send to other function to make an input type

Tags: javascript, json

I have a function that reads JSON but I want to send it to my other function to make an input type but I don't know how.

```js
var oXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
oXHR.onreadystatechange = reportStatus;
oXHR.open("GET", "file:///:\Users\khaldoun10\Desktop\NewHTMLPROJECT\html dynamic project\json.txt", true);
oXHR.send();

function reportStatus() {
  if (oXHR.readyState == 4) {
    document.getElementById('showData').innerHTML = this.responseText;
  }
}

objs.forEach(function(objs) {
  for (var k in objs) {
    if (objs[k] instanceof Object) {
      const formItem = objs[k];
      var elmn = document.createElement(objs[k].type);
      elmn.textContent = formItem.Text;

      Object.assign(elmn.style, {
        position: 'absolute',
        color: formItem.color,
        width: formItem.width,
        height: formItem.height,
        top: formItem.top,
        left: formItem.left,
        fontFamily: formItem.Font.fontName,
        fontSize: formItem.Font.font,
      });

      document.getElementById('ColorArea').appendChild(elmn);
    } else {
      console.log('Else');
    };
  }
});
```

json object:

```
var objs = [{
  "Object1": {
    "ID": 1,
    "type": "input",
    "color": "red",
    "Text": "DARKDRAGON",
    "width": "150px",
    "height": "40px",
    "top": "15px",
    "left": "5px",
    "Font": {
      "fontName": "tahoma",
      "font": "17px"
    }
  },
  "Object2": {
    "ID": 2,
    "type": "textarea",
    "color": "cyan",
    "Text": "SPEEDYTIGER",
    "width": "150px",
    "height": "40px",
    "top": "70px",
    "left": "5px",
    "Font": {
      "fontName": "tahoma",
      "font": "17px"
    }
  },
  "Object3": {
    "ID": 3,
    "type": "input",
    "color": "blue",
    "Text": "AMyesteriousAdults",
    "width": "200px",
    "height": "40px",
    "top": "130px",
    "left": "5px",
    "Font": {
      "fontName": "tahoma",
      "font": "17px"
    }
  },
  "Object4": {
    "ID": 4,
    "type": "button",
    "color": "darkorange",
    "Text": "AMyesteriousDarkSpeed",
    "width": "200px",
    "height": "40px",
    "top": "190px",
    "left": "5px",
    "Font": {
      "fontName": "tahoma",
      "font": "17px"
    }
  }
}]
```

Comment: Can you make a proper question ? Not a child like one.

Comment: if the system prompts you to include more information in your question, that's a signal to include more information, not to repeat the same minimal, not-very-informative text again and again! Also, you seem to be struggling with formatting - this guide can help you: [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). And you would also benefit from reading [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), I think.

Comment: Anyway, what is "my function", and "my other function". Tell us which ones you mean exactly. Right now, your code only contains one function! So we cannot possibly understand your request. Please explain specifically and clearly what you want to do, show the relevant code, and highlight the problem area.

Comment: JSON is a string notation. JSON objects do not exist. When you parse JSON, you get a POJO, Plain Old JavaScript Object

Comment: P.S. technical note, making AJAX requests to `file://` URLs is likely to cause you problems. Install a local webserver and then make requests to `http://localhost` instead. This will work far better and also simulate a live environment more accurately.

Comment: look i want the json object to in a file and in away i want to let it work in js

Comment: That doesn't answer any of the questions we asked. If we ask you for clarification, it's a good idea to actually provide answers to those instead of just making another very vague statement. We didn't ask for no reason.  P.S. If writing in English is a problem for you, please find someone to help you translate.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to ajax to a web server or include the JSON as a js object in the page
2. You needed to check the type. Buttons have innerHTML and other inputs have value

So assuming you change your

```
function reportStatus() {
  if (oXHR.readyState == 4) {
    document.getElementById('showData').innerHTML = this.responseText;
  }
}
```

to

```
function reportStatus() {
   if (this.readyState == 4) {
    format(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
   }
}
```

then you can have this [working version reading from json.txt file](https://plungjan.name/SO/ajaxjson/)

using this formatting code

```js
const format = objs => {
  Object.keys(objs[0]).forEach(key => {
    const formItem = objs[0][key];
    const elmn = document.createElement(formItem.type);
    if (formItem.type === "button") elmn.innerHTML = formItem.Text;
    else elmn.value = formItem.Text;
    Object.assign(elmn.style, {
      position: 'absolute',
      color: formItem.color,
      width: formItem.width,
      height: formItem.height,
      top: formItem.top,
      left: formItem.left,
      fontFamily: formItem.Font.fontName,
      fontSize: formItem.Font.font,
    });

    document.getElementById('ColorArea').appendChild(elmn);
  })
};
```

Working example of the formatting:

```js
const objs = [{ "Object1": { "ID": 1, "type": "input", "color": "red", "Text": "DARKDRAGON", "width": "150px", "height": "40px", "top": "15px", "left": "5px", "Font": { "fontName": "tahoma", "font": "17px" } }, "Object2": { "ID": 2, "type": "textarea", "color": "cyan", "Text": "SPEEDYTIGER", "width": "150px", "height": "40px", "top": "70px", "left": "5px", "Font": { "fontName": "tahoma", "font": "17px" } }, "Object3": { "ID": 3, "type": "input", "color": "blue", "Text": "AMyesteriousAdults", "width": "200px", "height": "40px", "top": "130px", "left": "5px", "Font": { "fontName": "tahoma", "font": "17px" } }, "Object4": { "ID": 4, "type": "button", "color": "darkorange", "Text": "AMyesteriousDarkSpeed", "width": "200px", "height": "40px", "top": "190px", "left": "5px", "Font": { "fontName": "tahoma", "font": "17px" } } }]

Object.keys(objs[0]).forEach(key => {

  const formItem = objs[0][key];
  const elmn = document.createElement(formItem.type);
  if (formItem.type === "button") elmn.innerHTML = formItem.Text;
  else elmn.value = formItem.Text;
  Object.assign(elmn.style, {
    position: 'absolute',
    color: formItem.color,
    width: formItem.width,
    height: formItem.height,
    top: formItem.top,
    left: formItem.left,
    fontFamily: formItem.Font.fontName,
    fontSize: formItem.Font.font,
  });

  document.getElementById('ColorArea').appendChild(elmn);
});
```

```html
<div id="ColorArea"></div>
```

Example HTML and script from my server - it will not run here because the json.txt is not available

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test JSON Ajax</title>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
      var oXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
      oXHR.onreadystatechange = reportStatus;
      oXHR.open("GET", "json.txt", true);
      oXHR.send();
    })
    function reportStatus() {
      if (this.readyState == 4) {
        format(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
      }
    }
    const format = objs => {
      Object.keys(objs[0]).forEach(key => {
        const formItem = objs[0][key];
        const elmn = document.createElement(formItem.type);
        if (formItem.type === "button") elmn.innerHTML = formItem.Text;
        else elmn.value = formItem.Text;
        Object.assign(elmn.style, {
          position: 'absolute',
          color: formItem.color,
          width: formItem.width,
          height: formItem.height,
          top: formItem.top,
          left: formItem.left,
          fontFamily: formItem.Font.fontName,
          fontSize: formItem.Font.font,
        });
        document.getElementById('ColorArea').appendChild(elmn);
      });
    };
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="ColorArea"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ok srry but first they gave me in error that is not working but when u sent the link i inspected it and took the script